# JS File running before my partialView completed loaded

Tags: javascript

I have a Js file running in my PartialView:

(innline my Partial)

I added the class in my DevExtreme element:

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().Button()
    .ID($"{baseId}CategoryNew")
    .ElementAttr(
    new
    {
        @class = "CategoryNew",
    })
    .Icon("add"))
```

but inside my js file I'm trying to add an event on a button (by class) :

```
$(".CategoryNew").click(function () {
    alert('test');
});
```

and doens't work, bucause my element with the class CategoryNew is not prepared yet, how can I fixed this "error".

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

You need to wait until the browser has fully loaded the page before trying to add event handlers, otherwise you’ll try to add them before the elements have been added to the DOM. `$(document).ready()` is a jQuery function that takes a callback of code to execute once the page has fully loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".CategoryNew").click(function() {
    alert('test');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At really, this approach I don't know why, doesn't work in my code, for example if a put a simple `alert('test');` in my js file the alert show before all element created